# Access Kedro MemoryDataSet when running packaged Kedro pipeline in a script

Tags: python, kedro

I want to be able to access a `MemoryDataSet` results dataframe from a kedro pipeline that I've imported into a script after packaging the pipeline into a python package.

I have a kedro pipeline written and run using `Kedro=0.18.9` that collects data, modifies it, then runs it against several anomaly detection algorithms. The pipeline loads from a database, saves all intermediate data (preprocessing, etc.) and results to CSVs at every step of the pipeline. It also returns the results of the anomaly detection to a `MemoryDataSet` in the last node. I've successfully detected anomalies by running the pipeline from the Kedro CLI. I've packaged up the pipeline using `kedro package` and pip installed this package in a different environment. I am able to run the pipeline in this new environment with `python -m my_kedro_pipeline` and when adding it to a script I get exactly what I would expect had I simply run it using the Kedro CLI.

```
from my_kedro_pipeline.__main__ import main
main()
```

I would like to be able to access this results `MemoryDataSet` in the new script and be able to assign it to a variable for use later in the script, but each time I call `main()` the script ends and I am not able to finish running the rest of the script.

The result that I'm looking for would look something like this, being able to run the pipeline with some runtime parameter setting and save the result to a variable for later use:

```
from my_kedro_pipeline.__main__ import main
import pandas as pd

results_df = pd.DataFrame()
results_df = main(['params', 'contamination=0.1']) #Grab results dataframe from last step of pipeline

anomalies = results_df.loc[results_df['ANOMALY SCORE'] == 1]

#For each anomaly in anomalies, print out that row of the dataframe
#and change a script flag based on its other column values
```

I have tried following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZdrp2MW80k) which is very outdated and even though kedro has changed since, I've been able to at least get the pipeline that I should be running, but I'm not sure how to "get" the catalog configuration from the pipeline package (or the parameters from `parameters.yml` for that matter):

```
import my_kedro_pipeline.pipeline_registry as registry
from kedro.io import DataCatalog
from kedro.runner import SequentialRunner

pipes = registry.register_pipelines()

#Would be something like
#my_kedro_pipeline.dataCatalog() or .get_conf()
not_the_right_catalog = DataCatalog()
runner = SequentialRunner()

results_df = runner.run(pipes['__default__'], not_the_right_catalog) #Something like this

anomalies = results_df.loc[results_df['ANOMALY SCORE'] == 1]

#For each anomaly in anomalies, print out that row of the dataframe
#and change a script flag based on its other column values, then do
#something with those set flags.
```

In Kedro=~17 there was a `load_context` function where you could at least pass a path to the pipeline source/config and you could load that like that person did in the tutorial, but I'm not sure how exactly that's changed since, and what the proper way to do it for a packaged pipeline is.

I would like to avoid a subproccess call and reading the results from the results CSV that I know gets written if possible, but if that's the only way, so be it (although I would find that hard to believe).

Answer (score 0):

The `KedroContext.run` method was deprecated in favor of `KedroSession.run`. As such, the way to programmatically run a pipeline would be creating a `KedroSession` as follows:

```py
from kedro.framework.session import KedroSession
from kedro.framework.startup import bootstrap_project
from pathlib import Path

project_root = Path.cwd()
bootstrap_project(project_root)

with KedroSession.create() as session:
    result = session.run(pipeline_name="__default__")
```

The variable `result` will then be a dictionary "any node outputs that cannot be processed by the DataCatalog", in other words: any output that is not registered in the catalog, hence `MemoryDataSet`.

More info on the docs: [Lifecycle management with KedroSession](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/kedro_project_setup/session.html)